# create and define properties and subproperties of a JS object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a variable x which may have or not have some property `propA`, and I would like to affect some subproperty `propA1`, and creating propA along the way if needed, so a valid code would be

```
if ('propA' in x) {
    x.propA.propA1='0'
} else {
    x.propA={'propA1' : 0}
}
```

or I could do something with `try..catch`, but I have actually some long lists of nested properties and I would like some umbrella assumption such as

```
x.propA.propA1=0
```

which does not raise an error if x does not have a `propA` property, but instead creates it with `{'propA1':0}`

Or maybe in a nice JS code all this properties should be defined since the beginning? Alternatively I would like

```
x.propA.propA1
```

to return `undefined` and not raise an error if `propA` is not defined, but I imagine it's not how it is intented to be...

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to know which approach is considered "best practice"? Or are you looking for help on how to implement one of the approaches you mentioned?

Comment: what's the bad to use `if ('propA' in x)` ?

Comment: I al just looking for something more compact and as I'm here good practices are always nice to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there's no equivalent of the new optional chaining operator for when you're *setting* a property, only when you're *getting* it.

What you're doing is already how you do this, though you can just test for the object rather than using `in`, which is might or might not be *slightly* more efficient but is definitely more idiomatic:

```
if (x.propA) { // *** Change is on this line
    x.propA.propA1='0'
} else {
    x.propA={'propA1' : 0}
}
```

That works because any object is truthy, and reading a non-existent property from an object results in the value `undefined`, which is falsy.

You can use a utility function for it if you like:

```
function setSub(obj, main, sub, value) {
    if (obj[main]) {
        obj[main][sub] = value;
    } else {
        obj[main] = {[sub]: value};
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Using it in your example:

```
setSub(x, "propA", "propA1", 0);
```

---

Another approach is to create a new object every time, which is frequently useful when following the guidelines of immutable programming, but does incur overhead:

```
x.propA = {...x.propA, propA1: 0};
```

Note that that even works when `x.propA` doesn't exist, because property spread notation explicitly allows spreading `undefined` and `null` — doing so adds no properties to the resulting object. So the above will copy the properties from `x.propA` if it's there, ignore it if it isn't, and include the `propA: 0` property in the result:

```js
const x1 = {};

x1.propA = {...x1.propA, propA1: 0};
console.log(x1);


const x2 = {propA: {}};

x2.propA = {...x2.propA, propA1: 0};
console.log(x2);


const x3 = {propA: {unrelated: "example"}};

x3.propA = {...x3.propA, propA1: 0};
console.log(x3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @MisterJojo - Since the OP's code would throw an error in that case (because the `in` test would be true and then they'd try to create a property on `null`), I think we can reasonably assume they don't do that.